# Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554438 bytes exceeds internal limit of 33554432 bytes Error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

I have MongoDB installed on `Aws(Ec2)` instance and `node` app running on ec2 instance. 
There is a huge data in one of my collection. So when I am pulling that data from DB so at the time of retrieving I am also sorting that data based on `time` key in descending order. But when I got a huge amount of data so it throws this error

```
Overflow sort stage buffered data usage of 33554438 bytes exceeds internal 
limit of 33554432 bytes
```

I read about this error and got the answer from StackOverflow that I should create an index on the sorted field i.e `time`. I created an index for `time` key. But I am still getting above mentioned error. Now I have 2 questions.

Q1) Do I still need `sort` in my query if I created an index at `time` key?
Q2) I have created an index at 'time' key and still have sort in my query and I am still getting an error. how I can resolve it?

Comment: Is time the only field you are sortning on in your query? For complex search/sort conditions, not all the indices might not be applicable: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

Comment: Please edit your question to include the results of [`explain(true)`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/) for this query. If adding an appropriate index did not resolve the in-memory sort it is likely that a different index is used than expected. Details of the query and explain output would confirm.

Comment: @Anton yes time is the only field on which i am sorting my data

Comment: @Stennie i don't know about `explain(true)` command and don'w know how to run this command and where to run this command